# Android AsyncTask to read data from a URL returns android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android and am making a global a high score feature for a simple minesweeper game I've made. I made the highscore feature using PHP so it just visits a URL with some get parameters and the score is saved automatically. To get the score is similar it should read the JSON contents of the URL into a String.

I know you can't access the network from the main thread so I created a AsyncTask. I then call it from my activity.

But I still get the error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Below is the AsyncTask class

```
package net.as93.minesweeper.util;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Eventupdate extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

String pageContents;

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... url) {
    try {

        Thread.sleep(4000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url[0]);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet,localContext);
        String result = "";
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            result += line + "\n";
        }
        pageContents = result;

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        e.printStackTrace();


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public String getPageContents() {
    return pageContents;
}
```

}

And here is the saveScore() method that should call the AsyncTask

```
public void saveScore(ScoreObj scoreObj) throws IOException {
        String usersname = scoreObj.getUsersName();
        String time = Integer.toString(scoreObj.getTime());
        String mode = scoreObj.getGameMode();
        String timed = ((scoreObj.isTimed()) ? "true" : "false");

        String myUri = "http://android.as93.net/minesweeper/setscore.php?usersname="+usersname+"&time="+time+"&timed="+timed+"&mode="+mode;
        try{
            Eventupdate eu = new Eventupdate();
            eu.execute(myUri);
            eu.doInBackground(myUri);


        }catch (Exception e){System.out.println("Another error: "+e);}


    }
```

I have already added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` to the manifest

I have been trying to figure this out for so many hours, can't find the solution on the internet anywhere. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Comment: Use an Asynctask for this purpose or http://blog.vogella.com/2012/02/22/android-strictmode-networkonmainthreadexception/

Comment: I am using an Asynctask I think - Eventupdate extends AsyncTask ?

Comment: @Lissy Also why this `Thread.sleep(4000);`??

Comment: Ooppss my bad, remove this line - eu.doInBackground(myUri); and you shall be fine

Comment: I tried that - it's still not working, can't think why :/

Comment: @Lissy still the same exception after removing `eu.doInBackground(myUri);`???

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: Ah that exceptions gone now - thanks :) although it's not working, just no error at all :/

Comment: The page contents returns null, when it should be either 1 or 0, and looking at the server it hasn't even visited that page

Comment: @Lissy remove this `Thread.sleep(4000);` and log some info in doInbackground and check the logcat

Comment: Thanks for your help @Raghunandan
Okay, got this error:
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "android.as93.net": No address associated with hostname
That sounded to me like a problem with the URL, but it can't be I've checked it and should be working fine - any ideas?

Comment: @Lissy yes it certainly problem with the url. Cross check again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this part right here is suspect

```
Eventupdate eu = new Eventupdate();
eu.execute(myUri);
eu.doInBackground(myUri);
```

do not directly call `doInBackground` when you call `execute` it will call that itself

Comment: Sorry for not accepting this sooner, only just saw it hadn't been accepted. Thanks for the answer, clearly put +1

Answer (score 2):

Remove this

```
eu.doInBackground(myUri);
```

You already have

```
eu.execute(myUri);
```

When you call execute AsyncTask in invoked and doInbackground does background computation

Answer (score 2):

In the try block remove eu.doInBackground(myUri);

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
eu.doInBackground(myUri);
```